# Android Studio (Ionic Gradle) - App isn't installed after Building

Tags: android-studio, gradle, ionic-framework

**Problem** After building, running in Android-Studio-Emulator: "App isn't installed".
What to do?

--Android Studio 2020.3

--Android SDK 30, Tools 30.0.2

--Gradle 7.0.2

...
I fail to see any proper Log in the emulator, maybe it's just me but coming from XCode this Android Studio is very poorly built, too bad. Hope someone can help.

[image]

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.midix.finance">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:name="com.midix.finance.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBarLaunch"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:exported="false">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="@string/custom_url_scheme" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

    <!-- Permissions -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Camera, Photos, input file -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!-- Geolocation API -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" />
    <!-- Navigator.getUserMedia -->
    <!-- Video -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <!-- Audio -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android studio is not poorly built. You need to learn its UI/UX and its functions just like how you learnt xCode.

1. I recommend debug your app in physical device. So connect your phone to the computer using USB cable (USB debugging must be turned on in your device).
2. Your device name must show in the place where Pixel 2 API 30 showing in your Android Studio screen.
3. Click on play button next to the device. After gradle building, app will be installed on your device. Authenticate your installation in your phone (Something says "Install this app?") after clicking play button.
4. Open "Logcat" option at the bottom to see any serious error logs coming.
5. If your app not installed means search the Logcat with your App package name. It will show why app not installed. Post your Logcat error to get accurate solution.

Comment: I do not own any Android devices, is "Logcat" available in Android studio?

Comment: Yes, Search the screen. Its at bottom of the screen (Logcat, build, etc options are present there)... Your project must be opened before opening logcat.